# Can't Install Android Development Toolkit: Says Missing JDK

Tags: java, android, installation, virtual-machine, windows-7-x64

I went to the Oracle site, downloaded and installed Java Platform (JDK) 7 on a Windows 7 64 bit virtual machine.  I added the path to the c:\program files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin to the path environment variable.  I even deleted c:\windows\system32\Java.exe as recommended by someone.  I was essentially following this: ["Android Create" call fails in windows 7 - missing JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052743/android-create-call-fails-in-windows-7-missing-jdk)

When I install the ADT it gives me the error JDK could not be found.  Download the latest JDK.  Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in the **ADT installer** , press `back` when the installer promite for `No JDK Found` then press `next`, the installer will find the `JDK`, for sure this is a common bug

Comment: Holy cow, I couldn't believe that's it but it is.  Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

this is caused because the Android DK finds java in the c:\windows\system32\ folder before it finds the JDK one.

To resolve this edit your PATH environment variable and put the JDK path before the c:\windows\system32\ path.

Answer (score 0):

Does that happen when you open eclipse?

I'm thinking in two possible problems. Here is one possible solution: [Eclipse - no Java (JRE) / (JDK) ... no virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine)

If you already got this, go to Window -> Android SDK and AVD preferences

The first "preference" should ask you your **Android** SDK folder. you need to set this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your JDK installation is not proper.

Reinstall JDK. It should be working fine.

I also had this problem once. I have done the above to resolve this issue.

You should not delete C:\Windows\System32 folder for this issue, It might lead to OS problems.

Comment: Yes, thanks, typo: meant I deleted Java.exe only.  I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

adil's answer is the one which finally worked for me (although I had added the jdk\bin to the path and created\set the JAVA_HOME to the same); moving the jdk\din directory before the win\sys32 in the PATH finally allowed me to install the android sdk on win7/64bit