# Android SDK - java not found

Tags: java, android

This problem was asked many times, but none of solutions doesnt help me.

I am using `Windows 7 SP1 (x64)`, `JDK 1.7.0_03 (x86)`, `JRE 7 (x86)` and `Android SDK Tools r16`.

When I install `Android SDK Tools` it says -

> Java SE Development Kit (JDK) version 1.7 has been found

But after install `SDK Manager` closes instantly. `android.bat` and `find_java.bat` say -

> WARNING: Java not found in your path.

I have tried set enviroment variables `JAVA_HOME`, `PATH` manually but this doesnt help. Searching solution many hours, setting variables, reinstalling java / sdk - nothing helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your path variables

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin

Comment: Have you seen these two answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3224830/302994 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/4853993/302994?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\ is the answer. The trailing \ is apparently very very important: without that the installer was not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android requires Java 1.5 or 1.6.

I haven't tested this, but I have seen posts about Android working with 1.7 as long as you also have 1.6 installed.  Although this requires having two versions of java installed, and I am not sure it's worth it.

Comment: Installed jdk-6u31. Same problem

Answer (score 3):

Install the x86 version, not the 64 bit version.

Comment: And it really ticks me off that the Android SDK installer doesn't specify...I went through JDK 7 and 6 in x64 versions before finally succeeding with JDK 6 x86.  What a waste of my time!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are using JRE, not JDK.
You can check which java you are using with: where java

Comment: in command line in windows, in Start menu - run, enter "cmd" and press enter, then you can get into the windows command line.

Answer (score 1):

I just set a Environment Variable named JAVA_HOME with the value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\ 
The problem is solved and sdk works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was facing the same problem, I found that the error might be a resolved by doing the following.

1. Download Android SDK, try to install, you get a java error (if you don't have it)
2. Typically you go download java, install and hit retry - but fail.
3. Adding JAVA_HOME didn't help, so I rebooted the pc and tried again.
4. Success, I don't know if it's the reboot after installing JAVA, or reboot after adding JAVA_HOME that solved the problem. One of them did the trick.

My recommendation is :
1. Install JAVA (in my case 1.7 x64), reboot.
2. Install android sdk, if it fails, add JAVA_HOME as explained above somewhere, reboot.
3. Install the sdk.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this may be outdated, but someone would probably find it useful. I had this problem myself, easiest(maybe dirty) solution I came up with is to change the default location when installing android studio.

Something like  this :

```
C:\Program files\Java\jdk-xxx\
```

to =>

```
C:\Program files(x86)\Java\jkd-xxx\
```

Installer is searching in x86 Program files folder probably for a 32bit version, but its working perfectly for me this way :)

Answer (score 0):

If you believe you have JDK installed and it was not properly recognized, set `SDK Location` on **Eclipse** (*Windows > Preference*). You can open/Update `SDK Manager` thru **Eclipse**.

Work fine in my `Windows 7 SP1 (x64)`, `JDK 1.7.0_03 (x64)`, `JRE 7 (x64)` and `Android SDK Tools r17`.