# SDK Manager exec:114 java not found error in Ubuntu while running SDK manager

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I have installed Java-ADT which is Android-SDK 64 bit version,installed jdk 64 bit version,installed jre 64 bit version,copied jre1.7.0_17 to eclipse folder and rename it to jre(after which I was able to run eclipse).

echo $PATH gives "/allSystemPaths:/pathToJDK:/PathToJDK/bin:/PathToJRE:/PathToJRE/bin:/PathToSDK/PlatformTools:/PathToSDK/tools"

echo $JAVA_HOME gives "/pathToJDK:/PathToJRE"

But when I run ANDROID SDK Manager still java not found error in android comes.I have searched a lot but not able to resolve it.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` must only contain the path to the `JDK`, having it in the form where there are multiple entries (i.e. the two directories) is an error, and will cause it not to be found

Comment: Tried also but still problem persists.

Comment: I've seen answers to similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9561108/27190) which suggest you might need JDK 1.6 in addition to 1.7.

Comment: when I run android sdk manager through terminal by typing android,then android sdk runs properly but throgh eclipse above error comes.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom JVM in eclipse.ini, according to [Eclipse documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini):

> One of the most recommended options to use is to specify a specific
>   JVM for Eclipse to run on. Doing this ensures that you are absolutely
>   certain which JVM Eclipse will run in and insulates you from system
>   changes that can alter the "default" JVM for your system. Many a user
>   has been tripped up because they thought they knew what JVM would be
>   used by default, but they thought wrong. eclipse.ini lets you be
>   CERTAIN.

In order to do that, you need to know where is your Eclipse home or define it. In a console run:

```
$ echo $ECLIPSE_HOME
```

If you get a path skip next step. If you get nothing, that means you've to define one. On your home directory just edit .bashrc file and at the last file add:

```
ECLIPSE_HOME=$HOME/.eclipse
```

After this your ECLIPSE_HOME will be /home/YOUR_USER/.eclipse

Once you've a defined ECLIPSE_HOME, you need to create or edit a file named eclipse.ini inside of your ECLIPSE_HOME directory. Such file should have the following content:

```
 -vm
 /opt/sun-jdk-1.6.0.02/bin/java
```

Where /opt/sun-jdk-1.6.0.02/bin/java is the absolute path to java.