# Android SDK won't run-Windows 7 ultimate x64

Tags: android, java, java-6

Whenever I try to launch Android SDK, a cmd window just flashes and nothing happens.

I have JDK version 1.6 and 1.7 installed. When I try to launch `Android.bat` from the tools folder, I get this: [(broken link)](http://up.vatandownload.com/images/kyqlr8q061dl5v5w76n0.jpg)

`Java.exe` is in system32. I've been searching for hours, but no solution.

---

**Edit**: Fixed, thanks to Phix, by installing 32 bit java.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052743/android-create-call-fails-in-windows-7-missing-jdk

Comment: have you tried adding the java bin path to your Path in system environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issues working with the 64bit version of the JDK.  Try using the 32bit version instead.