# Android Studio - Can't open AVD/SDK

Tags: java, android

Sorry if this is the wrong Stack Exchange, but this is where most of the questions were asked when I googled my problem.

For some time now I've been having problems with Android Studio and the AVD/SDK. It seems to be a relatively common problem, but I haven't been able to fix my problem with any of the solutions that worked for everyone else. This is the error I'm getting whenever I try and run the AVD or the SDK:

```
Cannot launch AVD manager.
Output:

Access is denied.

ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

If you already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME environment
variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System Settings to point to the
JDK folder.

You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html
```

I've tried re-installing everything Java (Both JRE and JDK), reinstalling Android Studio, running as admin, configuring permissions and a bunch of other stuff. I'm running Windows 7 and I've tried both JDK/JRE 6, 7 and 8 (JDK 6 worked very poorly though). I don't really know what kind of information you need to help me solve this problem, but I'll supply any information needed as fast as I can. Thank you very much.

**Edit:**
Please note that Java IS installed. Both `Java` and `Javac` is working fine in cmd.

Comment: have you tried to reload SDKs in ADT?

Comment: Get your Java working first.

Comment: @Prag's Could you please expand on that? I'm uncertain of what you mean.

Comment: what is the path of your SDK?

Comment: @Mighter Afaik the JDK should be working. Any way to test it?

Comment: Go to "Windows>Preferences>Android" in Eclipse..
What's the path of Your SDK there??

does both match?

Comment: @Prag's I added this to the Path variable:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin

Comment: @Prag's I'm not using Eclipse

Comment: open command manager(CMD)... write `java`  and press enter if it works means your java is OK

Comment: @Prag's It says in the title. Android Studio, Google's new IDE based on IntelliJ.

Comment: Both `Java` and `Javac` is working

Comment: fix your java by re installing latest jdk

Comment: @Yogamurthy I've tried this, didn't work.

Comment: you are using Windows 7 32bit or 64 bit?

Comment: this may helpful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052743/android-create-call-fails-in-windows-7-missing-jdk

Comment: Why is people downvoting this? I really have no idea what to do, I've googled this problem for so long and I still haven't found any answers that worked. I'm beginning to think my only option is to run Android Studio in a Virtual Box :(

Comment: @Prag's 64 bit. Both JRE and JDK is for 64 bit as well.

Comment: I took a look at that post, but I have already done this and javac is working fine. But seriously, thank you for helping me, even thought it's not fixed yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Solved my problem! Some software I had previously installed had created a Path in User Variables, which was the one I was using for my JDK path. I tried using the Path in System Variables and it worked just fine! Thanks to everyone who took time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest that Go to Windows  -> Preference -> Java -> Compiler 
And try with different java version.

Comment: I can't seem to find that. Are you sure this is for Android Studio and not eclipse?

Comment: this is for eclipse. but if you are having adt bundle then also option will come or this may help you. Just let me know if you are facing any problem. thanx

Comment: I'm using Google's new IDE Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Java folders are in the path (and that's why they work from CMD) but your JAVA_HOME is not defined.

As you are on Windows try creating a System Variable following [those steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

Comment: I have a JAVA_HOME variable and it's set to this: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60`

Comment: In that case... If you go to Project Structure -> SDKs does Your Java version appear there? Does it show any errors when you select it?

Answer (score 0):

Try (re)installing the [ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html) and see if it works. If not, go to the sdk's root folder (`[PATH TO THE UNZIPPED ADT]/sdk`) and open the `AVD Manager.exe`. Does it still give you the same error? If not, try to open the `SDK Manager.exe` and make sure you've installed all the propper APIs. I'd recommend installing at least the SDK Tools and Platfom-tools, and all of API19 (Android 4.4.2).

Comment: The only `AVD Manager.exe` I have is in `[PATH TO THE UNZIPPED ADT]\sdk\tools\lib`. Running that gave me [this error](http://puu.sh/9p0ie/00189fca1b.png).

Comment: Also, even opening the ADT bundle is a problem since it's giving me the same 'Access Denied' error I've seen so many times now. I'm beginning to suspect this has something to do with my Java and not Android Studio.